# Run LaTeX command in Sublime 3

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, pdflatex, bibtex

I'm working with LaTeX files in Sublime 3 (3059). Given a main `.tex` file and a `.bib` file holding the citations, I'd like to be able to issue the standard:

```
pdflatex main.tex && bibtex main.aux && pdflatex main.tex && pdflatex main.tex
```

command after hitting a given shortcut in Sublime.

I know there are tools that can do this (LatexTools, LaTeXing) but since what I need is (I believe) so simple, I'd prefer not to depend on extra packages.

How can I store this command and have Sublime run it following a given key combination?

---

Edit: Based on the answer given, this is the full command I ended up using:

```
{
    "cmd": ["pdflatex $file_name && bibtex $file_base_name.aux && pdflatex $file_name && pdflatex $file_name"],
    "shell": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a command you could use *Tools > Build System > New Build System* to create a file with a content similar to this one:

```
{
    "cmd": ["command"]
}
```

And then, you should select that as your project Build System. Finally, use *ctrl+b* to invoke build (invoke your command or script).

Comment: Could you give some more details on how to construct the full command?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. The `"shell": true` key was missing, I'll add the full cmmd to the question. Thank you..